# Class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related gives zero related product result

Tags: magento-1.8, products-view

I am currently trying to modify catalog/product/list/related.phtml, and I found out that it uses Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related.

I used `$this->getItems()->getSize()` to check the number of related products involve is correct. I verified that there is 1 related product owned by the current product. However, it says `0` in the result, and it would not display any related product, which does not make sense.

The block seems to work, but it does not display the related products although I verified that there is a related product. What should I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reason this might be the case:

- The related product in question is out of stock, disabled
- The related product is already in your cart, which disables magento from showing it

The best way to find out what is wrong is debugging Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related and the getItems function in there.

Comment: I made sure it is enabled. The funny thing is that I also tried to open it on another browser instance, and it says 1 and works. But when I refresh it on the same browser, it still says 0. Also wondering what specific cache does it come from?

Comment: Perhaps your session has become corrupted. Try cleaning the var/session directory and try again.