# Display all related products independently of cart

Tags: cart, product-relations

As per answerfrom Patrick Steenks [there](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25792/class-mage-catalog-block-product-list-related-gives-zero-related-product-result/25794#25794), when a related product is already in cart, it is not displayed in the related product block.

How to display it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite the method  `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related::_prepareData` and remove this

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
);
```